# How to access payload in apache-camel from a rest client when response code is 400?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel, jbossfuse

in camel route I am accessing a rest service. For invalid input I am getting below json response with 400 response code. But I cannot access the payload. Even it is not reflecting in camel body. Please help to give a solution that how to access the rest payload when response code is other than 200.

This below chunk is the route containing cxfrs:bean. I am trying to handle the exception in dotry block and then try to retrieve the response payload in processor. But payload is not accessible.

```
  <route id="_route3" streamCache="true">
     <from id="_from2" uri="direct:togetcustomercategorybackend"/>
       <doTry id="_doTry1">
         <to id="_to3" uri="cxfrs:bean:DsGetCustomerCategoryBackEndUrl"/>
      <doCatch id="_doCatch1">
      <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception> 
      <process ref="ResponseHandler" />
      </doCatch>
    </doTry>
  </route>
```

This is response from rest client. Please note the payload from backend with response code 400

```
ID: 923
Response-Code: 400
Encoding: UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Headers: {connection=[keep-alive], Content-Length=[98], 
content-type=[application/json; charset=utf-8],Date=[Mon, 16 Dec 2019 17:19:04 GMT], 
Server=[Kestrel]}
Payload: {"error":{"errorcode":"inv.offertype","errormessage":"Invalid offertype 
provided","errorinfo":""}}
```

Passing the request parameters using query params:

```
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;


public interface DSGetCustomerCategoryApi {


@GET    
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String DSGetCustomerCategory( 
        @QueryParam("OfferType") String OfferType, 
        @QueryParam("MSISDN") String MSISDN ,
        @QueryParam("IdType") String IdType ,
        @QueryParam("IdNumber") String IdNumber ,
        @QueryParam("BillAverage") Double BillAverage );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

when response code is other than 200 this means you got an exception and to get the exception body in your payload below example may help:
`public String getException(Exception exception) {
    return exception.getMessage();
}`